# Non-relativistic limit of complex scalar field Lagrangian

Tags: quantum-field-theory, schroedinger-equation, approximations, klein-gordon-equation

I am trying to derive the non-relativistic Lagrangian for a complex scalar field from taking the non-relativistic limit of the complex scalar field Lagrangian.  I am following the steps in "QFT for the Gifted Amateur," section 12.3, which uses the mostly-minus metric convention.

They start out with the complex scalar field Lagrangian (with interaction term),

$$\mathcal{L} = \partial^{\mu}\psi^{\dagger}\partial_{\mu}\psi-m^2\psi^{\dagger}\psi -\lambda(\psi^{\dagger}\psi)^2\tag{1} $$

and take the non-relativistic limit,

$$\psi \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}e^{-imt}\Psi(\textbf{x},t),\tag{2}$$

and the corresponding adjoint expression and plug them into $\mathcal{L}$.
The book first studied the time derivative part, and argues:

> As in the last example, the guts of taking the [non-relativistic] limit may be found in the time derivatives.  We find

$$ \partial_{0}\psi^{\dagger}\partial_{0}\psi = \frac{1}{2m} \left[ \partial_0 \Psi^{\dagger}\partial_0\Psi + im \left( \Psi^{\dagger}\partial_0\Psi - (\partial_0\Psi^{\dagger})\Psi    \right)  +m^2\Psi^{\dagger}\Psi   \right]. \tag{3}$$
The first term going as $1/m$ is negligible in comparison with the others.

I agree with the equation they derived, however, I don't know why the first term that goes as $(1/m)$ is negligible, because if you expand out the rest of the Lagrangian (this is now my work, not the textbook's,) you get

$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{m}{2}\Psi^{\dagger}\Psi + \frac{i}{2}\left( \Psi^{\dagger}\partial_0\Psi-(\partial^0\Psi^{\dagger})\Psi  \right) + \frac{1}{2m}\partial^0\Psi^{\dagger}\partial_0\Psi$$$$ - \frac{1}{2m}\nabla\Psi^{\dagger} \cdot \nabla\Psi - \frac{m}{2}\Psi^{\dagger}\Psi - \frac{\lambda}{4m^2}(\Psi^{\dagger}\Psi)^2. \tag{4}
$$

Then it is claimed that $\Psi$ and its adjoint may be expanded in plane waves, like

$$
\Psi = \sum a_{\textbf{p}}e^{-ip\cdot x},\tag{5}
$$

so $\left( \Psi^{\dagger}\partial_0\Psi - \Psi \partial_0\Psi^{\dagger}    \right)  $ can be replaced with $2\Psi^{\dagger}\partial_0\Psi$, which leaves

$$
\mathcal{L} = i\Psi^{\dagger}\partial_0\Psi + \frac{1}{2m}\partial^0\Psi^{\dagger}\partial_0\Psi - \frac{1}{2m}\nabla\Psi^{\dagger} \cdot \nabla \Psi - \frac{\lambda}{4m^2} (\Psi^{\dagger}{\Psi})^2.\tag{6}
$$

The algebra I am fine with, but I say that if you look at the full Lagrangian, not just the time derivative part, both the time derivative and spatial derivative parts go as $1/m$, and even worse, the interaction term goes as $1/m^2$.  The book neglected the time derivative part and uses as its final answer

> $$
> \mathcal{L} = i\Psi^{\dagger}\partial_0\Psi - \frac{1}{2m}\nabla\Psi^{\dagger} \cdot \nabla\Psi - \frac{\lambda}{4m^2} \left( \Psi^{\dagger}\Psi  \right)^2.
> \tag{7}$$

Is there a reason why the $\frac{1}{2m}\partial_0\Psi^{\dagger}\partial_0\Psi$ time-derivative term is neglected because "it is small compared to the other two terms in the time derivative $(\partial_0\Psi^{\dagger}\partial_0\Psi)$ expression", even though it is $\mathbf{not}$ small compared to the other terms in the Lagrangian (at least, I don't think it is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perhaps best seen via the [dispersion relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_relation) after doing a Fourier transformation to the energy-momentum representation. The time derivative $\partial_0$ corresponds (up to a factor of $i$) to multiplication with energy $E$ (which is the total energy minus the rest energy that was subtracted in eq. (2).).

In the non-relativistic (NR) limit, we are only interested in energy excitations $|E|\ll mc^2$, where $m$ is the rest mass. Therefore the quadratic time derivative term $\frac{1}{2m}\partial^0\Psi^{\dagger}\partial_0\Psi$ is small compared to the single time derivative term $i\Psi^{\dagger}\partial_0\Psi$, and can be neglected. (If we keep it, we will also find solutions $|E|\gg mc^2$ associated with antiparticles.)

Therefore we arrive at the Schroedinger Lagrangian (7). For this reduction from the complex [Klein-Gordon eq.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein-Gordon_equation) to the [Schr. eq.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation), see also e.g. A. Zee, *QFT in a Nutshell,* Chap. III.5, and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32383/2451) Phys.SE post plus links therein.

In order to quantize the Schroedinger Lagrangian (7), one needs to consider the Hamiltonian formulation. See e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15242/2451) Phys.SE post. The long story short is that we recognize the last two terms in eq. (7) as minus the Hamiltonian density $-{\cal H}$. The energy of a field configuration therefore comes from these two terms.

Comment: Ok, so if I plug the plane wave expansion into the Lagrangian and keep the terms in the same order as they are in my second equation from the bottom, then I get $\mathcal{L} = E\Psi^{\dagger}\Psi + \frac{E^2}{2m}\Psi^{\dagger}\Psi - \frac{p^2}{2m}\Psi^{\dagger}\Psi -\frac{\lambda}{4m^2}(\Psi^{\dagger}\Psi)^2. $
I can clearly see how the second term is negligible compared to the first.  Is there a reason why the second term is negligible compared to the third term, with the square of the momentum?

Comment: Only indirectly.

Comment: Oh, I might see it now.  If the energy E that is remaining is not including the rest energy, then $E = \frac{p^2}{2m}$.  Since we are investigating the case where $E\ll m$, then given E is just kinetic energy, then we get $E \ll \frac{p^2}{2E}$, or $E \ll p$.