# Dirac bracket for the Madelung (polar) form of the Schrodinger field

Tags: schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, constrained-dynamics, poisson-brackets

I'm having an issue with obtaining the Dirac bracket in the Madelung (polar) representation of the Schrödinger field:
\begin{equation}
  \Psi=\sqrt{\rho}e^{i\theta/\hbar}.
  \label{eq:WavefunctionPolarForm}
\end{equation}

Background:

It has been shown (for instance by Nonnenmacher https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02817982 and Guerra https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.28.1916) that in this representation, $\theta$ and $\rho$ play the role of conjugate variables in phase space $\Gamma=\left( \rho,\theta \right)$ with a Poisson bracket given by
\begin{equation}
  \left\{ f,g \right\}=\int d\vec{r}\left(\frac{\delta f}{\delta\rho}\frac{\delta g}{\delta\theta}-\frac{\delta f}{\delta\theta}\frac{\delta g}{\delta\rho}\right)=\left\{ f,g \right\}_{\rho,\theta}.
  \label{}
\end{equation}
Basically I would like to derive this result by applying the Dirac-Bergmann algorithm for constrained Hamiltonian systems.
However, there is an additional factor of $2$ which pops up in the resulting Dirac bracket, so that
\begin{equation}
  \left\{ f,g \right\}_D=2\left\{ f,g \right\}_{\rho,\theta}
  \label{}
\end{equation}
as shown below.
To begin with, note that a Hermitian Lagrangian density for the free Schrodinger field, may be written as (see for instance Henley & Thirring's 'Elementary QFT' or Peter Holland's 'The quantum theory of motion')
\begin{equation}
  \mathcal{L}=\frac{i\hbar}{2}\left( \Psi^*\dot{\Psi}-\dot{\Psi}^*\Psi\right)-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla\Psi\nabla\Psi^*.
  \label{}
\end{equation}
Variation of the action $I=\int dt d^3x\mathcal{L}$ with respect to $\Psi^*$ yields the Schroedinger equation and variation with respect to $\Psi$ yields its complex conjugate.
Substituting the polar form for $\Psi$ into this expression for $\mathcal{L}$, we obtain the following form for $\mathcal{L}$:
\begin{equation}
  \mathcal{L}=-\rho\left(\dot{\theta}+\frac{(\nabla\theta)^2}{2m}\right)-\frac{\hbar^2}{8m\rho}\left( \nabla\rho \right)^2.
  \label{eq:LagrangianPolarForm}
\end{equation}
Variation with respect to the field $\theta$ yields an equation of continuity:
\begin{equation}
  \dot{\rho}+\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{J}=0
  \label{}
\end{equation}
where $\vec{J}=\rho\vec{\nabla}\theta/m$, while variation with respect to $\rho$ yields the quantum Hamilton-Jacobi equation:
\begin{equation}
  \dot{\theta}+\frac{(\nabla\theta)^2}{2m}-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m\sqrt{\rho}}\nabla^2\sqrt{\rho}=0.
  \label{}
\end{equation}
It is well known that these $2$ wave equations map onto the Schroedinger equation.
Now, the canonical momenta, are then $\pi_{\rho}=0$ and $\pi_{\theta}=-\rho$, leading to the constraint equations $C_1=\pi_{\rho}\approx 0$ and $C_2=\pi_{\theta}+\rho\approx 0$ in the full phase space $(\rho,\theta,\pi_{\rho},\pi_{\theta})$, where following Dirac the symbol '$\approx$' denotes weak equality on hypersurface defined by the constraints.
The canonical Hamiltonian density is given by
\begin{equation}
  \mathcal{H}_c=\pi_{\theta}\dot{\theta}+\pi_{\rho}\dot{\rho}-\mathcal{L}\approx \rho\left( \frac{(\nabla\theta)^2}{2m}\right)+\frac{\hbar^2}{8m\rho}\left( \nabla\rho \right)^2.
  \label{eq:canonicalHamiltonianDensity}
\end{equation}
The Poisson bracket of the constraints, shows that they are second class: $\left\{ C_1\left( \vec{r} \right), C_2 \left( \vec{r}' \right) \right\}=-\delta \left( \vec{r}-\vec{r}' \right)$.

The matrix of constraint Poisson brackets with elements $Q_{ij}\left( \vec{r},\vec{r}' \right)=\left\{ C_i\left( \vec{r} \right),C_j\left( \vec{r}' \right) \right\}$, is then
\begin{equation}
  Q\left( \vec{r},\vec{r}' \right)=
  \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & -1\\
   1 & 0 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  \delta \left( \vec{r}-\vec{r}' \right),
  \label{eq:ConstraintPoissonMatrix}
\end{equation}
whose inverse is
\begin{equation}
  Q^{-1}\left( \vec{r},\vec{r}' \right)=
  \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 1\\
   -1 & 0 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  \delta \left( \vec{r}-\vec{r}' \right).
  \label{eq:ConstraintPoissonMatrixInverse}
\end{equation}

The Dirac bracket may be constructed, as
\begin{equation}
  \left\{ f\left(\vec{x}  \right),g\left( \vec{y} \right) \right\}_D=\left\{ f\left( \vec{x} \right),g\left( \vec{y} \right) \right\}-\sum_{i,j=1,2}\iint d\vec{r}d\vec{r}'\left\{ f\left( \vec{x} \right),C_i\left( \vec{r} \right) \right\}Q^{-1}_{ij}\left( \vec{r},\vec{r}' \right)\left\{ C_j\left( \vec{r}' \right),g\left( \vec{y} \right) \right\}=\left\{ f\left( \vec{x} \right),g\left( \vec{y} \right) \right\}-R_{12}-R_{21}.
  \label{}
\end{equation}
Now for $R_{12}$ one finds
\begin{equation}
  R_{12}=\int d\vec{r}\left( \frac{\delta f}{\delta\rho}\frac{\delta g}{\delta\pi_{\rho}}-\frac{\delta f}{\delta\rho}\frac{\delta g}{\delta\theta} \right),
  \label{}
\end{equation}
and for $R_{21}$:
\begin{equation}
  R_{21}=\int d\vec{r}\left( \frac{\delta f}{\delta\theta}\frac{\delta g}{\delta\rho}-\frac{\delta f}{\delta\pi_{\rho}}\frac{\delta g}{\delta\rho} \right).
  \label{}
\end{equation}
Hence, we have
\begin{equation}
  \left\{ f\left( \vec{x} \right),g\left( \vec{y} \right) \right\}_D=\int d\vec{r}\left( \frac{\delta f}{\delta\rho}\frac{\delta g}{\delta\pi_{\rho}}- \frac{\delta f}{\delta\pi_{\rho}}\frac{\delta g}{\delta\rho} + \frac{\delta f}{\delta\theta}\frac{\delta g}{\delta\pi_{\theta}}- \frac{\delta f}{\delta\pi_{\theta}}\frac{\delta g}{\delta\theta} - \frac{\delta f}{\delta\rho}\frac{\delta g}{\delta\pi_{\rho}}+\frac{\delta f}{\delta\rho}\frac{\delta g}{\delta\theta} -  \frac{\delta f}{\delta\theta}\frac{\delta g}{\delta\rho}+\frac{\delta f}{\delta\pi_{\rho}}\frac{\delta g}{\delta\rho}\right)= \int d\vec{r}\left( \frac{\delta f}{\delta\theta}\frac{\delta g}{\delta\pi_{\theta}}- \frac{\delta f}{\delta\pi_{\theta}}\frac{\delta g}{\delta\theta} +\frac{\delta f}{\delta\rho}\frac{\delta g}{\delta\theta} -  \frac{\delta f}{\delta\theta}\frac{\delta g}{\delta\rho}\right).
  \label{}
\end{equation}
Now if we make use of the constraint equation $\pi_{\theta}=-\rho$, we get that the Dirac bracket reduces to
\begin{equation}
  \left\{ f,g \right\}_D=2 \left\{ f,g \right\}_{\rho,\theta}.
  \label{}
\end{equation}
So the phase space is reduced to the variables $\rho$ and $\theta$ but the factor of $2$ really shouldn't be there as it leads to inconsistent wave equations for the $\rho$ and $\theta$ variables under e.g. $\dot{\theta}=\left\{ \rho,H_c \right\}_D$.
I have tried to add a total time derivative to the Lagrangian density to start with.. For instance
\begin{equation}
  \mathcal{L}\rightarrow\mathcal{L}'=\mathcal{L}+\frac{d}{dt}\left( \rho\theta/2 \right).
  \label{}
\end{equation}
But this ends up giving a factor of $4$ instead of $2$.. I have noticed that if the canonical momenta lead to the constraints $C_1=\pi_{\rho}-2\theta\approx 0$ and $C_2=\pi_{\theta}+2\rho\approx 0$, then the Dirac bracket reduces to the Poisson bracket $\left\{ f,g \right\}_{\rho,\theta}$ without any prefactor..
But it doesn't seem possible to add a total time derivative to $\mathcal{L}$ which achieves this.
Any thoughts at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your equation only contains first-order time derivatives and so is already of Hamiltonian action integral form: 
$$
S= \int (p_i\dot q_i -H(p,q)) dt
$$
with 
$$
p_i\mapsto \rho(x),\\
q_i \mapsto \theta(x),\\
i\mapsto x
$$
Dirac brackets are therefore unnecessary.
So,  from the continuum version of  $\{p_i,q_j\}=\delta_{ij}$ we read off that $\{\rho(x),\theta(x')\}= \delta(x-x')$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It did seem to me that might be the case. From the $4$ phase space variables $\rho,\theta,\pi_{\rho},\pi_{\theta}$, one of them is zero: $\pi_{\rho}=0$ while the other momentum is simply another field variable: $\pi_{\theta}=-\rho$. It was clear to me that $-\rho$ and $\theta$ are conjugate variables for the reason you have just stated - computing the Poisson bracket ${\rho(x),\theta(x')}=\delta(x-x')$ over the full phase space variables when supplementing the constraint $\pi_{\theta}=-\rho$.

Comment: But I still wanted to check that the Dirac bracket reduced to the Poisson bracket on the reduced phase space, yet this factor of $2$ pops up which shouldn't! It does seem that it has to do with double counting in some way from the $\pi_{\theta}=-\rho$, but not sure how to get rid of it.

Comment: I up-voted your answer but as I do not have 15 points yet it is not displayed..

Answer (score 2):

User mike stone is right. No need to go through the full Dirac-Bergmann analysis of constraints, which is done in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15242/2451) Phys.SE post. The [Faddeev-Jackiw method](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9306075) suffice: ${\cal L}$ is already on Hamiltonian first-order form, and $\rho$ and $\theta$ are canonical variables with canonical Poisson brackets $\{\rho({\bf x}),\theta({\bf y})\}=\delta^3({\bf x}-{\bf y})$.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of Jackiw's paper. It has the neatest proof of Darboux that I know.  I've been arguing that Dirac brackets are not always necessary for perhaps even longer than Roman J. See for example my ancient [Phys. Rev. Lett. 63, 731 (1989)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.63.731)!