# Diffusion equation Lagrangian: what is the conjugate field?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, complex-numbers, diffusion

Morse and Feshbach state on p. 313 without elaboration that the diffusion equation for temperature or concentration $\psi$ **and its "conjugate" $\psi^*$** (quotation marks *theirs*) has the Lagrangian density:

$$L=-\nabla\psi\cdot\nabla\psi^* 
-\frac{1}{2}a^2(\psi^*\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t}-\psi\frac{\partial\psi^*}{\partial t}).
$$

I don't understand what the conjugate field, $\psi^*$, is. Since the classical (non-Schrödinger) field should be real, I suspect the conjugation symbol * refers to something other than complex conjugation. With a real field, $\psi^*=\psi$, and only $-\nabla\psi\cdot\nabla\psi$ remains, which would be the Lagrangian for the Laplace equation (steady state diffusion).

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89002/why-treat-complex-scalar-field-and-its-complex-conjugate-as-two-different-fields).

Comment: Wick-rotated version of question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15242/2451

Comment: Morse and Feshbach elaborate on page 298

Answer (score 2):

The conjugate field ψ∗ is but the complex conjugate of *ψ*, so an extra degree of freedom to expedite derivation of the diffusion equation, 
$$
\nabla^2 \psi = a^2 \partial_t \psi ,
$$ 
analogous to the Lagrangian of the free [Schroedinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_field#Free_field), real in that case--only.

- But, since this equation does not mix real and imaginary parts, take its imaginary part to be zero at the very end, and safely interpret *ψ* as a concentration, etc.

It is just computational expedience, namely extending to the complex plane, as, e.g. in electromagnetism, to avoid the quandary you observed if you take the imaginary part of the Lagrangian, (proportional to *a*<sup>2</sup>) to vanish.

Alternatively, integrating by parts in the action and discarding the surface terms nets a Lagrangian density
$$
L= \psi^* (\nabla^2 -a^2 \partial_t )\psi,
$$
so ψ∗ may be thought of as an extraneous Lagrange multiplier gimmick to brutally enforce the diffusion equation as is, and concentrate on its real solutions.

Note $\int dx \psi $ is a constant in time, as physically required for your diffusing quantity.

A central solution of this equation underlying its propagator is 
$$
\psi({\mathbf x},t)= \frac{a^3}{8 (\pi t )^{3/2}} ~ e^{-a^2 {\mathbf x}^2  /4t}
$$
which starts out at *t* =0 as a Dirac $\delta ({\mathbf x})=\psi({\mathbf x},0)$. As a result, *any* initial concentration profile *f*  can be written as a linear superposition of such  *δ*s, 
$$
\tilde \psi({\mathbf x},0)= \int d^3 y ~ f({\mathbf y}  ) \delta ({\mathbf x} -{\mathbf y}) , 
$$
and propagated through each component thereof, by the above solution,
$$
\tilde \psi({\mathbf x},t)= \frac{a^3}{8 (\pi t )^{3/2}} ~\int d^3 y ~ \tilde \psi({\mathbf y},0  )    ~ e^{-a^2 ({\mathbf x}-{\mathbf y})^2  /4t}     . 
$$