# Lagrangian for a concentration field

Tags: thermodynamics, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, physical-chemistry

If I have a field, $\phi(x)$, representing the concentration of particles in a one dimensional space, what is the Lagrangian for this field? My initial guess was

$$\mathcal{L} = \int dx[\frac{1}{2}\dot{\phi}^2 -\frac{1}{2}\phi'^2 - \mu\phi]$$

where $U(\phi)=\mu\phi$ was interpreted from the thermodynamic equation $U=TS-PV+\mu N$.

However, after looking at [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/460991/), I see that the kinetic energy term might not be so straightforward for diffusion systems.